# Number of ways to arrange $a,b,c,d$ such that $a$ is not followed immediately by $b$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Can someone explain this solution?

The question is:

How many ways are there to arrange the letters $a,b,c,d$ such that
$a$ is not followed immediately by $b$?

The solution is:

$4! − 3! = 18$

I know that $4!$ comes from $4$ letters but where does $3!$ come from?

Comment: Hint:  think of $(ab)$ as a block.  There are $3!$ ways to arrange the three symbols $(ab),c,d$.

Comment: but it says a is not followed immediately by b ?

Comment: oh did u mean that a is not followed by b then we minus b ?so we have 3 letters left?

Comment: I was explaining where the $3!$ came from.  The basic idea is "take all the sequences and then subtract off those that do contain (ab) as a block".

Answer (score 4):

Determining the unwanted words:

Setting $u = ab$ we form words out of the set $\{ u, c, d \}$, where there are $3!$ ways to do it.

We can form $4!$ words out of $\{ a, b, c, d \}$, so we have $4! - 3!$ valid words.

Comment: Amazing explanation. How did you know repetition is not allowed please?

Comment: I guess I took this from the word "arrange". Meaning just changing positions of some given objects.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the comments:

The number of permutations which do not contain $(ab)$ is the Total Number of Permutations less the number of permutations which do contain $(ab)$.

The total number is clearly $4!$, as stated. So we just need to count the number of permutations that do contain $(ab)$.

To do that count, treat $(ab)$ as a block.  Then we are just after the number of permutations of $\{(ab),c,d\}$ but that is just $3!$

Hence the answer is the difference $4!-3!$.